# Default domain Azure web site

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

I have created an Azure Website called "MySite".

I have added my custom domain: www.mydomain.com

Before adding a custom domain the default preview-URL for the site in Azure portal is: mysite.azurewebsites.net

After adding my custom domain to the bindings I want the preview-URL to be: www.mydomain.com

How to achieve this? There doesnt seem to exist any sorting function.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the "preview-URL"?  Are you referring to the "URL" as shown on the Dashboard page of your web app in the Azure Management portal?

Comment: Yes Rick,  exactly,  in the dashboard / table list / blade.  In all of these places

Comment: The Azure Preview portal at https://portal.azure.com will show your custom domain in the URL field on web app blade instead of the default *.azurewebsites.net.